# all data values showing zero after updating via webscoket from broker api in python print contains 0,0,0,0,0

Tags: python, websocket, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading

```
 import time,os,datetime,math
 from time import sleep
 import logging
 from alice_blue import *
 import pandas as pd

 username = "AAAAAA"
 password = "AAAAAAA"
 api_secret = "AAAAAAA"
 twoFA = "AAAAAA"

access_token=
AliceBlue.login_and_get_access_token(username=username,password=password,twoFA=twoFA,api_se 
cret=api_secret)
alice = 
AliceBlue(username=username,password=password,access_token=access_token,master_contracts_to_download= 
['NSE'])

print("Master contract loaded succesfully")
print("\n")

print("Getting Profile Details ")
print("\n")
profile = alice.get_profile()
profile_data=(profile['data'])
exchange = profile_data['exchanges']
print("Name: ",profile_data['name']," Client Id: ",profile_data['login_id']," Pan card: ",profile_data["pan_number"],"Exchange : ",exchange[1])
print("\n")
balance = alice.get_balance()
balance_data = balance['data']
cash_position = balance_data['cash_positions']
print("Balance available is : ",cash_position[0]['utilized']['var_margin'])

print("Wait for breakout Time\n")

socket_opened = False
token = 0
open_price=0
high_price=0
low_price=0
close_price=0

def event_handler_quote_update(message):
    global token
    global open_price
    global high_price
    global close_price
    global low_price
    token = message['token']
    open_price = message['open']
    high_price = message['high']
    low_price = message['low']
    close_price = message['close']
def open_callback():
    global socket_opened
    socket_opened = True

alice.start_websocket(subscribe_callback=event_handler_quote_update,
                  socket_open_callback=open_callback,
                  run_in_background=True)
while(socket_opened==False):
    pass
alice.subscribe(alice.get_instrument_by_symbol("NSE","ONGC"), LiveFeedType.FULL_SNAPQUOTE)
print(token,open_price,high_price,low_price,close_price)
sleep(10)
```

Please someone help i am new to python and algo trading.
I am expecting the updated value from websocket and print in but it's unable to update and print same.Please help anyone.This is alice blue api for indian stock market which helps in algo trading. Everything working fine except updated data

Comment: Maybe its a real bad day in the stock market? With negative oil prices, zero-value stocks can't be far behind.

Comment: but right now it's not negative ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make the sleep directly behind your subscribe. It looks like an asynchonous call and your callback-function probably fires after you print your results.

Are you sure that your sleep is in the right line?

Edit:

You should maybe simply use the queue.Queue class. I hope this solves your problem. You can use the Queue simply like an normal list. As an example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep

def write_in_Queue(some_message, seconds):
    print("Wait {} seconds".format(seconds))
    sleep(seconds)
    queue.put(some_message)
    print('message put into Queue')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = Queue()
    threadpool = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    threadpool.submit(write_in_Queue, "Hallo", 2)
    threadpool.submit(write_in_Queue, "End", 4)

    print("Waiting for first message")
    message_1 = queue.get()
    print("Wait for second message")
    message_2 = queue.get()
    print(message_2)
    print("Finish this thread")
```

You will receive the output:

```
Wait 2 seconds
Wait 4 seconds
 Waiting for first message
message put into Queue
Wait for second message
message put into Queue
End
Finish this thread
```

The queue.get takes care that you wait until something is written into the Queue. I have tried to solve this with the asyncio library but could not find a solution to get this work so fast.

You would simply write your messages into the Queue. I hope this helps.

Comment: yaaah,sleep is at the right place because when i print whole message it works fine, but problem occurs when i extract the values from message and try to print

Comment: Yes, exactly. When you print your message, you do this in your callback function? The point is that your callback function is triggered after you print your extracted values.
 
Please try once, a sleep directly after your alice.subscribe and before your print. If this works, I can give you maybe some hints how you can fix this in future.

Comment: Yes yes this worked.!! Thanks a lot. my issue is fixed. apart from this please tell me hints

Comment: Okay, the point is that your callback-function is called asynchronously. 
Your callback-function will trigger always when you receive a message from the server, but you do not neccessarily know when this happens. This is the reason why your values were still Zero when you printed. You have not waited for the server's response. I would strongly advise you to use objects that deal with this concurrency problem. Give me please 10 Minutes I will change your code very shortly that it works like you want to.

Comment: Hey i have a issue again , suppose i want to extract 200 scrips so it will take too much time then, If i have to place order at 9:15 how can i spontaneously extract for all scrips

Comment: 200 messages? Are you using python3?

Comment: ins_scrip = [alice.get_instrument_by_symbol("NSE","TATAMOTORS"),alice.get_instrument_by_symbol("NSE","VEDL"),
             alice.get_instrument_by_symbol("NSE","RELIANCE"),alice.get_instrument_by_symbol("NSE","IOC"),
             alice.get_instrument_by_symbol("NSE","HDFC"),alice.get_instrument_by_symbol("NSE","PFC")]
for i in ins_scrip:
    alice.subscribe(i,LiveFeedType.FULL_SNAPQUOTE)
    sleep(1)
    print("Token:",token,"Open:",open_price,"High:",high_price,"Low:",low_price,"Close:",close_price)

This is the code i have written for five scrips data i am getting is slow then.

Comment: yaaah i am using python 3.6

Comment: Okay, do I assume that you actually only want to receive these values once and not really subscribe to these?

Comment: well i have need for both, but it will be ok with retrieving once at 9:15  for all scrips.

Comment: I believe you can simply use
result = alice.get_instrument_by_symbol("NSE","TATAMOTORS") as an example.
 
I at least believe this from the documentation. This should be your easiest approach. 

If you want to go the subscription way, I would advise you to take a look into Queues (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-queue.html) or Locks (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html) in general the library would help you with the synchronizationsproblem.

Comment: if i  wiill not use the subscribe i will not get open high low close as alice.get_instrument_by_smbool is ued only to search the name in master contract.

Comment: [link](https://pypi.org/project/alice-blue/) This is the link for python documentation of api.